# Embed "i" tag into "a" tag in CakePHP

Tags: html, cakephp, tags

With CakePHP 3.7.9 I want to place an `i` tag (to shown an icon) inside an `a` tag. Here my code:

```
private function resetButton(array $options = []):string
{
    $params = $this->_View->getRequest()->getQueryParams();
    if (!empty($params)) {
        foreach ($params as $field => $value) {
            if (substr($field, 0, 7) === 'Filter-') {
                unset($params[$field]);
            }
        }
    }
    $options = Hash::merge($this->getConfig('resetButtonOptions'), $options);
    $url = Hash::merge($this->request->params, [
        'resetFilter' => true
    ]);

    return $this->Html->link($this->Html->tag('i', '', ['class' => 'fa fa-eraser']), Router::reverse($url), $options);
}
```

this renders to:

```
<a href="/products?_csrfToken=blablabla;resetFilter=1" class="btn btn-default" pass="1">&lt;i class="fa fa-eraser"&gt;&lt;/i&gt;</a>
```

that means it's translated literally, instead I want to generate an `i` tag.
If I open the developer tools of my broswer, delete the inner html of the `a` tag and paste the expected content (`<i class="fa fa-eraser"></i>`) it renders correctly.

Is my PHP sentence above wrong?

Comment: Check the `escapeTitle` option. **https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/html.html#creating-links**

Comment: @ndm, yep it actually works. Because used an helper to create the `i` tag (and not a literal string) I thought it wouldn't escape it - it makes no sense to me.

Comment: The helper method returns a string too, so it's not any different than passing a string directly.

Comment: @ndm, shouldn't be `escape` instead of the `escapeTitle`, since the tag is in the 'body' of the link, and not in it's title attribute....?

Comment: @LinkinTED The term `Title` in `escapeTitle` doesn't refer to the `title` attribute, but to the `$title` method argument. The `escape` option would apply to the `$title` argument as well as to all attributes, which is usually not desired, and has the potential for creating XSS vulnerabilities when user input isn't handled with care.